# Can you reverse bivariate interpolate to output an x and y value for a given z value using a x,y,z matrix?

Tags: excel, interpolation

I am trying to obtain an estimate of an x and y value given a z value using a x,y,z matrix. I am not sure how to do this in excel. I am able to do bi-linear interpolation if I know the x and y values to obtain a z value but I am not sure how to do the reverse process.

[image: this link is an image of the matrix with the x values being CFM (top), Y values being Ps (left side) and the z Values are FEPref (inside the matrix)]

Answer (score 0):

This is an under-constrained problem, as there are multiple z values that are the same.  In fact, it appears that the contours of the z-values imply that any given z-value would have many potential interpolated answers, assuming that your underlying model is continuous (not discrete).  Hence, there is not an answer to your question as posed.